# SQL chunk update with JOIN

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a 2 tables in my DB, one contain data about clients (called Clients), the other table contains clientID, Guid, AddedTime and IsValid (called ClientsToUpdate).

ClientID is related to the clients table, Guid is a unique identifier, AddedTime is the time when the record was added to the table, and IsValid is a bit indicated if this ClientID was updated or not.

What I want to do, is update all the Clients that their ID is in ClientsToUpdate, the problem is, the ClientsToUpdate table contains over than 80,000 records and I am getting deadlocks.

What I though I can do, is update 2000 clients at a time, using a while loop or something similar.

MY Stored Procedure looks like:

```
UPDATE client SET LastLogin=GETDATE() 
FROM Clients client
JOIN ClientsToUpdate ctu ON client.ID = ctu.ClientID;
```

Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @done table (ClientID int primary key)
while 1=1
    begin

    update  top (2000) c
    set     lastlogin = getdate()
    output  deleted.id into @done
    from    Clients c
    join    ClientsToUpdate ctu
    on      c.id = ctu.ClientID
    where   not exists
            (
            select  *
            from    @done d
            where   d.ClientID = ctu.ClientID
            )

    if @@rowcount = 0
        break
    end
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20a93/3/0)

Comment: Basically he's updating the top 2000 rows of his query that meets the where condition until all 80000 rows have been traversed. He stored the Ids of the updated rows into @done to check against (the nested select *). When @@rowcount =0, that means nothing has been updated, thus nothing is left TO BE UPDATED it's time to break out of the loop.

Comment: Andomar, is that supposed to be updated.ids and not deleted.ids?

Comment: @Yatrix: since the `id` column does not change, you can use both `deleted` (column values before update) and `inserted` (column values after update.)  I don't think there is an `updated` special table.

Comment: Interesting. And confusing. Hehe.

Answer (score 0):

If you experience deadlocks, updating in chunks might reduce errors (assuming you carefully manage your transactions and commit your chunk updates), but does not resolve the deadlocks origin. IMHO you should investigate lock problems and find why you have deadlocks